# Making a property visible, only during scrolling

Tags: javascript, html, css

I'm trying to make a box shadow property only visible during scrolling. I'm using HTML, CSS and JS.

I want the shadow to appear with a small transition when scrolling then disappear when stopped.

So far I have been using this code:

```
<head>
    <title>website</title>
    <link href="style.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
    <script type="text/javascript" src="script.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
    <div id="mySidenav" class="sidenav" onscroll="scrollShadow()"></div>
```

css

```
.sidenav {
height: 100%;
width: 280px;
position: fixed;
z-index: 1;
top: 0;
left: 0;
background-color: skyblue;
overflow-x: hidden;
transition: 0.5s;
padding-top: 10px;
}
```

js

```
function scrollShadow() {
document.getElementsByClassName("sidenav").style.boxShadow = "3px 0px 10px black"; 
}
```

Would love any help!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Instead of setting the style attribute, which is harder to manage (especially if you have more than one element you want to affect), you could set a class on `body` and style the elements with CSS.

```js
(function iife() {
    var body = document.body;
    var timer;
  
    window.addEventListener('scroll', function onScroll() {
        clearTimeout(timer);
        body.classList.add('scrolling');
    
        timer = setTimeout(function removeClass() {
         body.classList.remove('scrolling');
        }, 150);
    }, false);
})();
```

```css
*, *:before, *:after {
  box-sizing: border-box;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

#container {
  width: 100vw;
  height: 5000px;
  background: lightgrey;
  transition: background 5s;
}

.scrolling #container {
  background: red;
}

#fix {
  position: fixed;
  top: 50px;
  left: 50px;
  height: 120px;
  width: 20px;
  background: white;
  transition: all 300ms ease 0s;
}

.scrolling #fix {
  box-shadow: 0 4px 8px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.35);
  transform: translateY(-3px);
}
```

```html
<div id="container">
  <div id="fix"></div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

u can use jquery scroll method as

```
<script>
   $(function(){
       $(window).scroll(function(){
           if($(window).scrollTop()>=40){
                /*do something */
               scrollShadow();
           }
       });
   });

   function scrollShadow() {
       document.getElementsByClassName("sidenav").style.boxShadow = "3px 0px     10px black"; 
  }
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

I would first ensure that you refrain from adding CSS inside JS, it just shouldn't live there. You can achieve what you want by adding a class to the body which is then targeted inside your CSS. Finally, there's no native way of knowing if the user has stopped scrolling. The only way is to define a timeout which will remove the class unless the user scrolls, whereby the original timeout is cancelled and a new timeout is defined. It's also best to make sure that the window is completely loaded else you'll be targeting elements that aren't there yet. This example below should be what you need:

```js
window.addEventListener('load', function(){

    var timeout = null;
    var body = document.querySelector('body');
    var scrollClass = 'scrolled';

    window.addEventListener('scroll', function(){
        clearTimeout(timeout);
        body.classList.add(scrollClass);

        timeout = setTimeout(function(){
            body.classList.remove(scrollClass);
        }, 250);
    });

});
```

```css
body {
  height: 2000px;
}

.sidenav {
    height: 100%;
    width: 280px;
    position: fixed;
    z-index: 1;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    background-color: skyblue;
    overflow-x: hidden;
    padding-top: 10px;
    transition: box-shadow 500ms ease-in-out;
}

.scrolled .sidenav{
    box-shadow: 3px 0px 10px #000;
}
```

```html
<div class="sidenav"></div>
```

This should achieve what you want.

Tom